# How to enable Site Speed at Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I installed the google analytics js code in my site, but the Site Speed report everytime is 0%, dont show me the reality. I saw google help about this in [About Site Speed](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&utm_content=sitespeed&topic=1120718&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=newga-blog&utm_source=gablog&answer=1205784) but how we can see, dont work.

Anyone know which can be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, Google Analytics only tracks the speed of 1% of all page views. This sample rate might be lower as only Chrome and Firefox are supported. You can increase the sample rate with a custom setting:

> sampleRate: Value between 0 - 100 to define the percentage of visitors to your site that will be measured for Site Speed purposes. For example, a value of 5 sets the Site Speed collection sample to 5%.

**Async Snippet (recommended)**

```
_gaq.push(['_setSiteSpeedSampleRate', 5]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

**Traditional (ga.js) Snippet**

```
pageTracker._setSiteSpeedSampleRate(5);
pageTracker._trackPageview();
```

Source: [Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration.html#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setSiteSpeedSampleRate)

Comment: Thanks, i did not see this information at analytics doc. Google did not show in "pt-br", only "en".

Comment: Is there any reason performance reasons for not sampling all the requests i.e. 100%

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that uploading the timing samples might not be desirable to have for each and every request.